# Using Both Grep and Cut

Tags: command-line, grep, cut, tcpdump

I want to grep the output of tcpdump and cut some part of it but the command below is not working.

```
tcpdump ... | grep -i --line-buffered "..." | cut -d'&' -f1,2
```

Do you know what is the problem? I guess it is because tcpdump produces real time data but I have no idea how solve this problem.

Comment: & might need escaping

Comment: please provide us with one of the tcpdump lines you want parsed and what you put for "..." in your grep search

Comment: Use the `-l` option with tcpdump.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-l` option with tcpdump.

> -l     Make stdout line buffered.  Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it.  E.g.,
>                 `tcpdump  -l  |  tee dat'' or`tcpdump  -l   > dat  &  tail  -f  dat''.

Clearly stated in the man page.

```
tcpdump -l ... | grep -i "..." | cut -d'&' -f1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `tcpdump` to a file through a background process and then use `tail -F <file> --pid=$!` to follow it.

So, something like

```
tcpdump ... > tcpdump.log 2>&1 &
tail -F tcpdump.log --pid=$! | grep -i --line-buffered "..." | cut -d '&' -f1,2
```